# handling blank values in url with url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am doing url rewriting for my shopping cart website and these I want to rewrite the url of login page. But when user came from shopping cart page there are few parameters that are appended to the url, so that based on that we can redirect the user to shopping cart again. And one case if that user directly came to login page from login hyperlink. so in this case the additional values are null.

I wrote the url rewriting rules as given below.

```
RewriteRule ^login/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*[^/])$ /index.php?file=login&ichangeid=$1&to=$2&from=$3&msg=$4
```

It's works fine when all the four parameter are passed to the url but when to and from parameter are null, means user directly came to login page then the first parameter of the url is passed to $1 and rest //some_message are passed to $2 and $3 and $4 not getting stored.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. But you could make the parameters optional by using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^login(?:/(.*))(?:/(.*))(?:/(.*))(?:/(.*[^/]))$ /index.php?file=login&ichangeid=$1&to=$2&from=$3&msg=$4
```